# Associate web session with user's workstation

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session

We are currently building a web-based application that has the need to associate a user with the physical workstation they are on. Ideally the application would be *confined to the browser* meaning no client application running on the machine outside of the browser.

There isn't a restriction on what information is used to track the workstation (IP, Mac Addr, Workstation Name), however a static IP is not guaranteed; the network may use DHCP.

Basically the question is: **is there a way to associate a web user's session with a physical machine, from within the browser**.

Please note that IE8 is the targeted browser; and a PHP framework such as CakePHP or Symfony will be used.

EDIT: Any static information to link the machine is acceptable it doesn't *have* to be Mac Address. Also users can move machines so we need to update their machine when they move preferably automatically without interaction from them.

Comment: if the user is confied to a browser; won't cookies work?

Comment: The user can *potentially* move around though not often. We need a peice of static information about the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your "Basically..." question is: Probably not, and if there is, you can't rely on it to stick around.

While I realize you have a target browser at this time, you should still probably design your tools to accommodate future software or policy changes.  Requiring ActiveX is probably not the best idea.

If you have other authentication systems available, you can attach to them.  There are options for BrowserID, NTLM and other techniques available for *AMP stacks, and I suspect Symfony support any of them would be fairly easy to find.  I've used [NTLM with Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/44718) for internal web applications with great success.  If you're using Active Directory to store user info, web apps can authenticate using LDAP and record persistent cookies.

If you're afraid that cookies may be removed, you can consider an [Evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/).  While that won't be associated with the physical machine (i.e. it won't withstand an OS reinstall), it's pretty dang close.

Comment: This is not an internal application. Although it will be used by business who need to identify a login with a workstation, I'm thinking that "type in your mac address" may have to happen.

Comment: We decided that evercookie may help us accomplish what we are trying to do, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this but the client will need ActiveX components enabled:

http://codingresource.blogspot.com/2010/02/get-client-mac-address-ip-address-using.html

Comment: We would prefer not to use an activex control

Comment: Try the solutions on http://forums.devarticles.com/general-programming-help-4/how-can-i-find-out-the-user-mac-address-1846.html